# C#: Using LINQ on a derived iterator class when both the derived class and its base implement IEnumerable

Tags: c#, linq, inheritance, ienumerable

I have a situation where I have iterator classes that I'm deriving. The base iterators iterate over base objects and the derived iterators iterator over derived objects. I can use LINQ on the base iterators but not on the derived iterators. It would be quite helpful if I could iterate over either using LINQ.

Thanks in advance for any guidance!

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class BaseThingy { }

    public class DerivedThingy : BaseThingy { }

    public class BaseEnumerator : IReadOnlyCollection<BaseThingy>
    {
        public int Count => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public IEnumerator<BaseThingy> GetEnumerator()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public class DerivedEnumerator : BaseEnumerator, IReadOnlyCollection<DerivedThingy>
    {
        IEnumerator<DerivedThingy> IEnumerable<DerivedThingy>.GetEnumerator()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public class Application
    {
        public void Main()
        {
            BaseEnumerator baseEnumerator = new BaseEnumerator();
            DerivedEnumerator derivedEnumerator = new DerivedEnumerator();

            // Works...
            var x = baseEnumerator.Where(s => s.GetHashCode() == s.GetHashCode());

            // Doesn't work...
            var y = derivedEnumerator.Where(s => s.GetHashCode() == s.GetHashCode());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"Doesn't work..."* in which way? Could you give the compiler error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `DerivedEnumerator` implements both `IEnumerable<BaseThingy>` and `IEnumerable<DerivedThingy>` (indirectly via `IReadOnlyColleciton`). So when you do

```
var y = derivedEnumerator.Where(s => s.GetHashCode() == s.GetHashCode());
```

Compiler cannot figure out what is the type of `s` in lamdba. Is that `DerivedThingy`? Is that `BaseThingy`? Both are possible. So you need to tell it explicitly what that is:

```
var y = derivedEnumerator.Where<DerivedThingy>(s => s.GetHashCode() == s.GetHashCode());
```

or

```
var y = derivedEnumerator.Where((DerivedThingy s) => s.GetHashCode() == s.GetHashCode());
```

That said, it's quite unusual design and you might reconsider it. How exactly depends on what you are trying to do (so, why do you need to inherit enumerators this way).

Comment: Hi Evk, thank you for the feedback. I'm certainly open to improving the design, and any suggestions you have would be appreciated. For simplicity, an abstraction of the problem would be: Suppose you have "Vehicle" and "Vehicles" classes, "Vehicles" obviously being the enumerator class. And suppose you wanted to derive the classes "Car" and "Cars". (And later you might want to derive classes "Motorcycle" and "Motorcycles"). Do you still see a flaw in the design of inheriting both the base class and its enumerator? Thanks again, Ryan.

Comment: @RyanHartstein I've yet to meet practical case of doing that. I mean - why inherit Cars from Vehicles? One can argue even that collection of Cars is not collection of Vehicles, because you can add any Vehicle (motorcycle) to collection of Vehicles, but you cannot add motorcycle to collection of Cars. Most collection stuff is perfectly handled by generic collections (`List<Car>`, `List<Vehicle>`) or generic interfaces (`IEnumerable`). I don't remember I have ever inherited collection classes in this way (or even ever though about doing that).

Comment: Thank you for your repsonse.

Answer (score 0):

Ambiguity issue

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class BaseThingy { }

    public class DerivedThingy : BaseThingy { }

    public class BaseEnumerator : IReadOnlyCollection<BaseThingy>
    {
        public int Count => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public IEnumerator<BaseThingy> GetEnumerator()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public class DerivedEnumerator : BaseEnumerator, IReadOnlyCollection<DerivedThingy>
    {
        IEnumerator<DerivedThingy> IEnumerable<DerivedThingy>.GetEnumerator()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public class Application
    {
        public void Main()
        {
            BaseEnumerator baseEnumerator = new BaseEnumerator();
            DerivedEnumerator derivedEnumerator = new DerivedEnumerator();

            // Works...
            var x = baseEnumerator.Where(s => s.GetHashCode() == s.GetHashCode());

            // Works now
            var y = derivedEnumerator.Where<DerivedThingy>(s => s.GetHashCode() == s.GetHashCode());
        }
    }
}
```